# Folium - Style Function with Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, lambda, folium

I am trying to create a Folium map which styles the polygon(s) based on conditional logic. I have a nested JSON object and I want to style the polygon based on the 'name' attribute.

I can iterate over my nested JSON object like this:

```
for i, element in enumerate(rguResource['features']):
    print(rguResource['features'][i]['properties']['name'])
```

The issue with my code snippit below is that it does not currently iterate over the object since I am specifying the index directly. If somebody could help me to combine my iteration logic above into the lambda function below, I would be really grateful.

Or, alternatively, I am open to a different way to styling the polygons if there is a different approach. I am trying to implement what was featured in the documentation (https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html).

Many thanks

```
geo_json = folium.GeoJson(
    rguResource, 
    
     style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': 'green' if rguResource['features'][0]['properties']['name'] == 'some string' else 'blue',
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 1,
        'dashArray': '5, 5',
        'fillOpacity':0.5
    })


geo_json.add_to(m)
```